# Not able to do escape query

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-cluster

iam new to cassandra,
i want to do get query using cassandra python client? iam not able to escape special characters.can anyone help 
Below is the query which iam trying, but getting syntax error

> SELECT pmid FROM chemical WHERE mentions=$$
>   N,N'-((1Z,3Z)-1,4-bis(4-methoxyphenyl)buta-1,3-diene-2,3-diyl)diformamide
>   $$ AND pmid=31134000 ALLOW FILTERING;

it is giving me error
Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:118 mismatched input '-' expecting ')' (...,source) VALUES ('be75372a-c311-11e9-ac2c-0a0df85af938','N,N'[-]...)"

Comment: I don't see any special characters in your string

Comment: iam getting syntax error,when iam doing above query @KostasCharitidis
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:118 mismatched input '-' expecting ')' (...,source) VALUES ('dbee12c0-c313-11e9-ad8f-0a0df85af938','N,N'[-]...)">

Comment: Can you provide more of the python code that you are using?. With the information provided, you may want to use a prepared statement, there are multiple examples in https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/api/cassandra/query/ . Also, please, avoid the use of `ALLOW FILTERING` (https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2)

Comment: I haven't used cassandra, but are your sure that this is the correct syntax? Try to run your query outside python to check if runs correctly and then pass it inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Syntax Provided as i see there is a Single quotes missing in your Query .

**Suggestion** 
Note to use **ALLOW FILTERING**  as it will Scan your Table which will be a performance issue.